# Secure file using Java in Windows

Tags: java, windows, file, permissions

I am developing client-server application in Java which need user login. For that I need to show login screen to enter user name & password if username is not there in configuration file (initially it should should be "blank").

After filling the form and checking the Remember Password, I am going to send user name and **digested password** to server to check. If user is there at server I will get success message then I need to save the username and digested password in a secure file if he check the Remember password checkbox at userlogin screen. For that I need a secure place to store username and password in Windows environment. If I store it in a file, how to secure that file from other users who logged into Windows with other username.

For every Windows user I need a **separate login** and I am using SHA-256 digesting algorithm to digest password.

How can I do it using Java Swing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a file, you should use the [Preferences API](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaPreferences/article.html). On Windows, it will store the data in the registry, in a branch not accessible to other (non-admin) users.